# Join Search Query on firebase, how?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to conduct simple search query as below.

```
SELECT post.title as "Post Title", user.email as "Author Email"
FROM User 
JOIN Post ON User.id = Post.userID
WHERE Post.title LIKE '%retriever%';
```

I know I can't do join search on nested collection

so I ended up creating two root collections: users, posts.

Below is my pathetic try on such query

```
const db = firebase.firestore() 

const ref = db.collection('Post')

const postTitle = await ref
  .orderBy('title')
  .startAt('Springfield')
  .get();
  
const userEmail = await db.collection('User') 
  .where('id', '==', 'postTitle.userId')
  .document('email');
```

How do I achieve the above result in this particular case?

Comment: `'postTitle.userId'` - unless that's the actual variable, remove the single quotes and it might produce what you're looking for. Just the first thing I saw.

Comment: @Torewin is this the right way of doing it though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, first let me confirm I understand the SQL.

You're wanting to return two variables (title, email) from the User table

```
SELECT post.title as "Post Title", user.email as "Author Email"
FROM User
```

Then you want to join the Post table where the 'User.id' is equal to the 'Post.userID' so essentially finding the users' posts.

```
JOIN Post ON User.id = Post.userID
WHERE Post.title LIKE '%retriever%';
```

If my assessment is accurate, and without knowing your data model, I can give a rough guess on what that would look like.

```
//Reference to Firestore
const db = firebase.firestore() 

//Reference to the Post "table" Collection
const ref = db.collection('Post')

//This is assuming I know the USER ID that I need - if I don't have it, we can retrieve it by their email 'admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email)' or somewhere else.
//This example should still work with whatever the 'id' key is representing in the Post model
    const postsByUserID = await ref.where('id', '==', userID).get();

if (postsByUserID.empty) {
  console.log('No matching documents.');
  return;
}  

//This will loop through every Post that we got that matched the user's ID
postsByUserID.forEach(doc => {
  console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
});
```

Keep in mind this is assuming that 'id' from your Post model is equal to a user's UID.

If we assume we do not know the user's ID, and want to get every user, and then the posts that have the 'id' equal to that user's id:

```
//Reference to the Post "table" Collection
const ref = db.collection('Users')

const allUsers = await ref.get();

allUsers.forEach(doc => {
  console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
  const userID = doc.data().id;

  const postsByUserID = await ref.where('id', '==', userID).get();

  if (postsByUserID.empty) {
    console.log('No matching documents.');
    return;
  }  

  //This will loop through every Post that we got that matched the user's ID
  postsByUserID.forEach(doc => {
    console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
  });
```

});

Comment: I am not sure if I am reading your understanding correctly, but let me elaborate on situation. So let's say a user wants to search by post that's related to retriever. The user types in retriever. In this case we need author's name that is NOT existent in post. Post refers to userId to retrieve the data from user. So in this case, the variable we receive is "%retriever%" which is the search term. So in the end, my goal is to find appropriate data that I want to show to user based on the search term.

Comment: Hmm, if I am understanding you then you essentially just want to make a simple search on Posts based on a query? For example, I have a Post with the title "This is a Brown Fox", and I query for "Fox". It should return this Post? Yes?

Comment: yes and the user email from. User collection as well

Comment: Firestore cannot query 'strings' that are LIKE a string. You can query documents that are exactly "This is a Brown Fox", but not find documents that contains "Fox". 

You can do this if you are separating keywords or tags into an array and then query if one of those strings are in that array, but you still wouldn't be able to type in "Fo" and have it retrieve "Fox".

If you can assume that the search term will ALWAYS be exact (or a Bool or Number range) then that is possible.

Comment: Thanks again for elaboration. I did not quite understand 'you can do this if you are separating keywords or tags into an array and then query if one of those strings are in that array, ' . Would you mind showing me an example of some sort?

Comment: For example, you can have a field in Firestore of type array with ["this", "is", "a", "brown", "fox"] and then you can do a `.where(key, "contains-in", "fox")` to see if that array has that term. If you're looking for a full search/query solution - I use Algolia, but there's plenty of other options.